# How to configure SSL in Azure Application GateWay with intermediate certificate and pfx file?

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-application-gateway

I have an Azure Application GateWay listening to 443 and redirecting traffic to
3 VM (ubuntu) listening to port 80 with nginx has reverse proxy, which redirect to pm2 node server, this is for Server Side Rendering with Angular Universal

When I create a new Listener in the Application Gateway I upload the pfx file
[image]

Now when I browse my sites I get a secure connection, but when I try to share a url in social media like facebook, twitter or linkedin I get an error with the certificate, so images and keywords are not displayed

I found this site that allows me to check SSL configurations (https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html), the results shows that I´m missing the intermediate certificate

- If I install the SSL into a VM without the Application Gateway and redirect clients to that VM, then everything works great.
- I have been changing Listeners, Rules and even try SSL Settings which is in preview, but no luck so far

Any idea what am I missing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that the public certificate ?.

Comment: I bought the certificate in DonDominio and it was issued by Digicert

Comment: Which SKU are you using for appgw?

Comment: Standard V2 with autoscale

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps somebody else. There are some SSL providers that do not include the intermediate certificate in the .pfx file, so you have to do this yourself in order to make it work in Azure Application Gateway. Steps are really simple:

1. Install OpenSSL (Yes, even if you buy the SSL)
2. Download the files(.key, .crt, .ca.crt) from your provider into a folder
3. Execute this command: openssl pkcs12 -export -out [certificate-name].pfx -inkey [certificate-name].key -in [certificate-name].crt -certfile [certificate-name].ca.crt , this will include the intermediate certificate into your .pfx file
4. Upload the .pfx file to your application gateway

Comment: I found key and crt.  where would ca.cert be?

Comment: In my case, the ca.cert is provided by my SLL provider along with .key and .crt . Since every provider can be a little bit different I would recommend you to ask them

Comment: I actually had a little confusion re: file names and what they "should" be.  In my case, I had a .pem and .cert files, which were the ones i needed to gen the pfx.

Comment: I haven try myself, but in theory  with those two files should be enough , try executing this: openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx  -in certificate.pem -certfile certificate.crt